# How to view a list of Scheduled Tasks for current user

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way using either SCHTASKS or C# to output a list of scheduled tasks for the current user?

Answer (score 1):

use WMI

```
  var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ScheduledJob");
  var tasks = query.Get();
```

there is also a [library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx) that you can use
you can also use [schtasks command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)